# Why process always exited when running systemd

Tags: linux, celery, systemd

why my service always exited when running systemd?
if change dir manualy to var/www/enterprise/src/ and execute /var/www/env/bin/celery -A catalog.tasks beat , proccess work perfectly

```
  root@debian-django-nginx:/var/www/enterprise/src# cat /etc/systemd/system/celerybeat.service 
[Unit]
Description=celery beat

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/enterprise/src/
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/www/env/bin/celery -A catalog.tasks beat &
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target 
root@debian-django-nginx:/var/www/enterprise/src# systemctl daemon-reload 
root@debian-django-nginx:/var/www/enterprise/src# systemctl start celerybeat
root@debian-django-nginx:/var/www/enterprise/src# systemctl status celerybeat
● celerybeat.service - celery beat
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celerybeat.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-02-28 15:01:52 +10; 1 weeks 0 days ago

Mar 07 14:11:55 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: celerybeat.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
Mar 07 14:28:08 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: Started celery beat.
Mar 07 14:39:34 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: Started celery beat.
Mar 07 15:05:56 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: Started celery beat.
Mar 07 15:08:46 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: Started celery beat.
Mar 07 15:19:35 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: Started celery beat.
Mar 07 15:33:38 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: Started celery beat.
```

Comment: What's logged in the journal?

Comment: Typically, btw, this kind of error means you're depending on environment variables or other setup that's available for your interactive shell but that you haven't set up in your service definition above.

Comment: Mar 07 15:19:35 debian-django-nginx systemd[1]: Started celery beat.
lines 33-66/66 (END)

Comment: There's going to be more than that -- *at minimum*, systemd will know the exit status of what it invoked; that info will be in `systemctl status yourservicename` and `systemctl show yourservicename` (albeit hidden among a bunch of other details in the latter).

Comment: By the way -- [Sysdig](http://sysdig.org/) is your friend; if you want a full trace of everything done by a given service, `sysdig 'thread.cgroups contains yourservicename'` will do the job (where, as always, `yourservicename` is the name your `.service` file is saved under).

Comment: Hmm. `active (exited)` typically means that the `RemainAfterExit` flag is enabled. You aren't showing that in your config file here -- are you sure the active configuration *really* matches up with what's in your question? Keep in mind that config-file fragments &c. can modify it, and that if you didn't run a `systemctl daemon-reload` your in-memory configuration can be out-of-date.

Comment: ...and if you want to see your *real* configuration and state, well, that's what the `systemctl show` command is good for.

Comment: systemctl show celerybeat.service | grep Remain
RemainAfterExit=no

Comment: You've asked a variation of a systemd FAQ [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).